# Text doesn't show on a game (Wine)

Tags: wine, fonts, games

The game, SMMWE, formally Super Mario Maker World Engine, was working perfectly, as in no problems, a few versions ago (that is, and older version of the game, not older wine).

When I decided to upgrade to version 3.2.2, all the text dissapeared! Appart from that, no issues. The buttons worked, the save and load functions worked, even the online mode worked! Just no text.

I think this happens because of the game's custom font. I think so because the same issue happened to RPG Maker XP in a tutorial, which was a font problem fixed by `sudo apt install`ing `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, which I did do, yet the problem persisted. Even so, I'm not sure if it's a font problem.

Things I tried :

- Installing `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`
- Installing `corefonts`,`tahoma`, and many others from winetricks
  Things I have yet to try :
- Installing `allfonts` from winetricks

Is there any way I can fix this?

(I will post screenshots as soon as I get access to my Ubuntu machine)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with other software, I had `allfonts` and the rest installed, still no fonts.

The solution for me was to get a Windows 10 default font pack, and extract them to `.wine/drive_c/windows/Fonts/`

This fixed it for me.

(so in your specific case, maybe try to obtain the game custom font(s) and throw them in the wine Fonts directory?)